# Deriving Contract Reference from `ink::trait_definition`

Tags: ink, rust, contracts, cross-contract-call, trait

Is it possible to create a [Contract Reference](https://use.ink/basics/cross-contract-calling/#contract-references) to perform a Cross-Contract call from `ink::trait_definition`?

If it is, how can I do so?

If it is not, why it is not possible? It seems strange that we can only create a reference to the whole contract and not to a single trait the contract is implementing.

Comment: using [this](https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts#wrapper-around-traits) you can create a reference of single trait

Answer (score 1):

There is a macro that based on ink trait creates an associated type for safe cross-contract calls:

https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink/macro.contract_ref.html